# How to make a todo linked to two parts of a document?

Tags: todonotes

I want to make a `todo` that would be linked to two parts of the document. For the moment it is only linked to one part :

[image]

Here is [a read-only link](https://www.overleaf.com/read/tzhwfmyzgjmr) to the code. Here is part of the code :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{todonotes}
\begin{document}

\subsection{Check whether $B$ is a logical consequence \todo{What's a logical consequence ? What is the difference with "conclusion" ?}  of $A$ and $B \vee C$. Explain your answer}


$A \wedge (B \vee C)\models^? B$

I would say that $B$ isn't a logical consequence of it but rather $B\wedge$ something, may it be $A$ or $C$.


\subsection{Is the argument with premises $A$ and $B \vee C$ and as conclusion B valid ? Explain why}

\end{document}
```

You can git-clone the project with this link : https://git.overleaf.com/12786207zcnhmcswktxn

Comment: Nice question, however it would help (for future questions) if you make a self-contained example (like the one in my answer), to make it easier for potential answerers to start implementing a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `todonotes` package keeps track of the current note with the node name `inNote`, and draws a line between the position in the text and the note. If you want to draw an extra line to the previous note, you can use the same node name. The following MWE, similar to the implementation of `todonotes`, creates a new node in the text called `inTextExtra` and draws a line from this node to the previously created `inNote` node.

The color is hardcoded and the note is expected to be found in the right margin (using `inNote.west`).

When you want to use this inside of a `subsection` title you should `\protect` the command. To stop the command from removing space between words you can add an extra `{}`.

This solution always refers back to the most recent previously defined note, if you want to refer to another note it becomes more complicated (in that case you must modify `todonotes` to create distinct node names).

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{todonotes}
\begin{document}

\newcommand{\extraline}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay, baseline=-0.75ex]%
\node [coordinate] (inTextExtra) {};%
\draw[thick,orange]%
([yshift=-0.2cm] inTextExtra)%
-| ([xshift=-0.2cm] inNote.west)%
-| (inNote.west);%
\end{tikzpicture}%
}

\newcommand{\abc}{xyz}

\section{Double notes}
\subsection{Check whether $B$ is a logical consequence \todo{What's a logical consequence ? What is the difference with "conclusion" ?}  of $A$ and $B \vee C$. Explain your answer}


$A \wedge (B \vee C)\models^? B$

I would say that $B$ isn't a logical consequence of it but rather $B\wedge$ something, may it be $A$ or $C$.

\subsection{Is the argument with premises $A$ and $B \vee C$ and as conclusion\protect\extraline {} B valid ? Explain why}

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Great ! Another question, do you now how to include them in a `\begin{align}...` ?

Comment: @Marine1 I'm not sure what you mean exactly, include what in the align environment? Is this problem related to the issue of multiple references to a note? If not, then it would be better to ask a new question (or to see if the question is already answered somewhere on the site). If the solution above does not work together with align, which is of course possible, then I could try to extend it.